# How to run eclipse hawkbit update server with java and use containers for rabbitmq/mysql/simulater

Tags: eclipse-hawkbit, hawkbit

I am new to community, I am new to eclipse hawkbit i would really appreciate it if someone could help me fix this issue I have:

I want run hawkbit through java but if I do I have to disable rabbitmq but I need RabbitMQ. docker already starts the containers when I start up the PC along with the update server simulator too.

Is it possible to run the update server through java and run rabbitmq etc through docker containers will it work like that?
Because obviously if I run hawkbit through docker and java there will be port problems 8080 will have already been used for docker, so maybe could someone tell me if there is a way to only run Rabbitmq, simulator and the mysql containers and run the update server as a java application?

Excuse the question but I am quite lost regarding this because ofcourse i have tried to stop the containers etc but it always restarts instantly.

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Hey @artur_roomman of course you can run hawkbit with plain java against a RabbitMQ instance in docker. As far as I understood your problem you are using the [example compose/stack file](https://github.com/eclipse/hawkbit/tree/master/hawkbit-runtime/docker) that provides the necessary containers for hawkbit and the included hawkbit instance conflicts with your local instance that you want to execute with java.

To stop hawkbit from being part of the stack you can just delete/comment the `hawkbit` service references in the docker-compose file and rerun `docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans` this should update the stack to not include the hawkbit service and remove the container.

To prevent containers from comming up automatically when being stopped just replace `restart: always` with `restart: unless-stopped` in the compose file, this will prevent restarts of containers when stopping them manually.

*Note: the compose file in the hawkbit repository is just an example to get started, it is not secured and e.g. exposes the DB without a password, it should not be used for production use cases*